# How to successfully query a database for 0 applicants using LINQ

Tags: asp.net, linq

I am trying to debug this code to make sure that it queries a database for users that have zero applications for the week using LINQ. When I connect it with an HTML.ActionLink I am getting no proper filter results.

```
 case "No_Activity":
                    dateCriteria = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);
                    students = students.Where(s => db.JPApplications.Where(a => a.ApplicationUserId == s.ApplicationUserId && a.JPApplicationDate >= dateCriteria).Count() == 0);
                    break;
```

Comment: Can you see what is being run on the database? What are "no proper filter results"? No results or unexpected results? How is students populated?

Comment: var studients = FROM s IN db.JPStudients WHERE s.JPHired == false SELECT s;

Comment: Also, no results as meaning it is not filtering studients who have zero applications for the week. I am getting unexpected results, when I click the actionlink I am getting no change to the view what so ever. The results I am expecting are to have it where it shows only stuidents who have zero applications for the week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add ToList() because students for this is IQueryable try this :

```
students = students.Where(s => !db.JPApplications.Any(a => a.ApplicationUserId == s.ApplicationUserId && a.JPApplicationDate >= dateCriteria)).ToList()
```

and Init your date like this:

```
dateCriteria = DateTime.ToDay.AddDays(-7)
```

I replaced the **count==0** by **!Any()**

Comment: count==0 should equate to !Any()

Comment: I am missing a cast somewhere. I am getting the error Cannot implicitly convert type 'system.collections.generic.list<JobPlacementDashboard.Models.JPStudent>' to 'System.Linq.Iqueryable<JobPlacementDashboard.Models.JPStudient'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cost?)

Comment: IQueryable<JPStudent> students

Comment: put a List<JPStudent> students  instead of IQueryable<JPStudent> students

Comment: I still don't understand. I don't understand how to cast IQuerable to a list, and then pass the list off. This is part of a switch case statement which accepts multiple variations and I am not sure of which algorithm to use to correct this.

Comment: You've declare `students` as `IQueryable<JPStudent>` but ToList() will return `List<JPStudent>`. These types are obviously not the same and one cannot be implicitly converted to another. However, both `List` and `IQueryable` implement `IEnumerable` so you could try declaring the variable as IEnumerable<JPStudent>. This may not expose all the methods you need elsewhere in your code but will resolve this specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have tables `Students` and `Applications`. There is a one-to-many relation between `Students` and `Applications`: Every `Student` has zero or more `Applications`, and every `Application` is owned (created by?) exactly one `Student`, using a foreign key.

Furthermore every `Application` has a (DateTime?) property `ApplicationDate`.

> Requirement:
>   Given a (DateTime) variable dateCriterium, query all Students that didn't submit any Application on or after dateCriterium.

In baby steps: the Students and all applications that were submitted on or after dateCriterium:

```
DateTime dateCriterium = ...
IQueryable<Student> students = ...
IQueryable<Application> applicationsAfterDate = allApplications
    .Where(application => application.ApplicationDate >= dateCriterium);
```

Extract the Ids of all Students that did submit any of these applications. Remove duplicates:

```
var idsOfStudentsWithApplicationsOnOrAfterDate = applicationsAfterDate
    .Select(application => application.StudentId)
    .Distinct();
```

Fetch all students that have an Id that is not in the list of student Ids of students that submitted an application on or after date = that does not contain the student Id

```
var studentsWithoutApplicationsOnOrAfterDate = students
    .Where(student => !idsOfStudentsWithApplicationsOnOrAfterDate.Contains(student.Id));
```

Until now you only created the query, no the database is not queried yet:

```
var result = studentsWithoutApplicationsOnOrAfterDate.ToList();
```

TODO: if desired you can put this in one big LINQ statement. As you didn't query the database until the ToList, this won't improve performence. It surely will deteriorate the readability of the code.